# Issues installing interbase/firebird PHP extension on MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, firebird, interbase

I'm currently having issues trying to install interbase support (interbase PHP extension) on my Mac MAMP PRO installation (with PHP 5.5 selected).

Here are the steps I did and didn't enable it:

```
cd Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/include/php/ext/interbase

phpize

./configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/bin/php-config

make

make install
```

It tells me that the library has been successfully installed:

```
Libraries have been installed in:
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/include/php/ext/interbase/modules
```

And it also tells me that the MAMP extensions has been updated:

```
Installing shared extensions:    
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/
```

After all these steps and restarting Apache, I can find the interbase.so file inside this folder, but I don't see the extension enabled in phpinfo() or get_loaded_extensions().

Can someone give me some help with this issue ?

I'm having this LOG error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'interbase.so' in Unknown on line 0
```

Thanks a lot, it's really appreciated!

**Edit: I did have put an extension=interbase.so in my php.ini MAMP template.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed every steps within this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24690411/3032516 and I recompiled php with the --with-php-config flag and it **solved** my issue.

Also, this link was very **helpful** to me: https://jellystyle.com/2012/12/installing-php-extensions-with-mamp

Comment: mark this answer as accepted, or other users with same problem may wrongly recognize my upvoted answer as "right", or even close the tab as it seems to lack accepted answer, so - not solved.

Answer (score 2):

Add/uncoment extension in `php.ini`.

Find for extension in `php.ini`:

```
;extension=php_interbase.dll
```

and uncomment/add it:

```
extension=interbase/modules/php_interbase.dll
```

Also, check if you properly configured extensions directory:

```
extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/include/php/ext"
```

Comment: Thanks ! However I've already put the extension line within my php.ini file. Thanks though. Also, my extension_dir is set to a MAMP variable.

Comment: Also, there isn't dll file in a Mac system. It's interbase.so.

Comment: i've just copied line from my php.ini on win machine =) hovewer, do you certain, that yours `extension=` line in conjunction with `extension_dir = ` line points exactly to the folder, where your's `interbase.so` resides?

Comment: yes ! 100% certain! :) My folder is : /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ and contains interbase.so.

Comment: and you certain, that server is using php from your's MAMP folder, not the default installed one?

Comment: As per my phpinfo(): extension_dir => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/ => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/

Comment: @DavidPearson, did you checked [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php#94268)?

Comment: that's exactly what I tried to do earlier, but nothing has worked. I'm sure this is something very specific that I miss.

Comment: I just discovered that I have this log error message : PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'interbase.so' in Unknown on line 0